# How to wait for Promise in a non-async function? (node-mssql)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I need to migrate to a MS SQL database and I'm using the [node-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) library.

Problem: the `mssql` library returns Promises and they don't block the execution of my code.

But my code expects the code to block and I cannot effort refactoring the whole project so I'm looking for a solution to wait for a Promise until it's done and to return its result.

All answers I found do not solve the problem.

When my code queries the database then it must return a result, not a Promise object that is resolved somewhen later. My code needs to block and wait for the Promise to finish (succeed or fail) and continue with its result.

I see that many others do have the same requirement. Why is it so hard to implement an `await`-like statement in a non-async function? These fancy Promise bullsh*t callbacks are driving you crazy.

An acceptable alternative is to switch to another MS SQL library that acts "like normal".

Here's an example:

```js
// Emulate the node-mssql connect method
// Similar to: const sql = require('mssql')
const sql = {
  connect: (config) => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({query: (sql) => sql}), 2000)
  })
}

// Existing project structure
class Foo {
  db; // database connection
  
  constructor() {
    this.db_connect();
  }
  
  db_connect() {
    this.db = sql.connect(); // Promise, not connection object
    // must not return until done!
  }
  
  db_query(sql) {
    return this.db.query(sql); // Promise, not result object
    // must not return until done!
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.db_query(`SELECT * FROM bar WHERE spam='eggs'`));

// Uncaught TypeError: this.db.query is not a function
```

Comment: There are exactly two possiblities `let result = await anAsyncFunction()` or `anAsyncFunction().then(result => ...)`. But there is no possibility whatsoever to make an asynchronous function synchronous ...

Comment: Similar answers are found everywhere and it does not solve the problem: You cannot use `await` for several reasons: class method is not an async function and if you would make it async, the method's return value is a Promise that leads to the same problem for the calling method. And `then()` is useless because it handles the result somewhen later but the method cannot return it. But this is needed because the calling method needs to process the result.

Comment: That's because you seem to not have understood yet that you can't make your code time-travel - you can't make something synchronous return the result of something asynchronous that is known only later in time. You need to make everything else asynchronous too! This means: `db_connect` must also be `async` and `db_query` too, as must be the main function that calls it. Once one thing is asynchronous, everything that calls it (and everything that calls _that_, etc.) must also be asynchronous. You _can_ use `await` - you just have to _make everything else `async` too_, then it's solved.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, because the solution you want simply doesn't exist in javascript ...

Comment: "class method is not an async function" << that's the issue. it _must_ be `async`, because it calls something that is `async`. "if you would make it async, the method's return value is a Promise that leads to the same problem for the calling method" << right, so the calling method _must also be `async`_, as must be _its_ caller, and so on, all the way up to the module itself. It must eventually be `console.log(await foo.db_query('...'))`.

Comment: I don't want to time-travel. I need simple sequential processing. If `await` is allowed in async functions then it proves that it **is** possible to block code execution... just not designed for non-async functions.

Comment: It's not really blocking code execution. It's simply yielding back to the event loop. It's only _logically_ "blocking" something, not _physically_. Other code will run in the meantime. (If you get to understand how [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) was used in the past to emulate the not-yet-existing `async`/`await` using generators and `yield`, you will understand this too.) - You can also read my deep dive into this concepts of logically/physically [here](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1442#issuecomment-592679689).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/328193)  (Hint: It does.  It may not be the answer you want, but it's the answer.  Alternatively, you can certainly look for data access libraries which synchronously block execution.  I don't know of any, and if there are any I'd expect them to be pretty old.)

Comment: No `await` doesn't block anything. It might seem like so when you look at the code. But behind the scenes there is something totally different happening, which is nicely hidden by `async` and `await`

Comment: *fancy Promise .... callbacks* - and that's all they are ... Promise .then is just a callback. If you can use `setTimeout` then you know how to use callbacks - don't let the P word scare you

Comment: Also: "I need simple sequential processing." << then you picked the wrong programming language. Perhaps switch to Python, it works the way you expect.

Comment: Making everything `async` requires a complete refactoring. And if you `await` all the time then the whole thing becomes non-async again... not really worth it. Hum, is there any alternative mssql library that does not return promises?

Comment: "Making everything async requires a complete refactoring." << That's right, and that's what you need to do. "And if you await all the time then the whole thing becomes non-async again... " << No, because you can still have multiple requests processed in parallel! "Hum, is there any alternative mssql library that does not return promises?" << if there is, it's old and generally a bad idea to use, because you are single-threaded - blocking is always extremely bad because it prevents all other things (such as other users' requests) from being processed and introduces a total bottleneck.

Comment: *"And if you await all the time then the whole thing becomes non-async again*". No. If you say that, you clearly haven't understood Promises or what `async` and `await` do

Comment: @droptix: *"Making everything async requires a complete refactoring."* - There's either a requirement in place to update the codebase or there isn't. If this is part of that update then it's part of the effort. *"And if you await all the time then the whole thing becomes non-async again... not really worth it."* - What you have there is a fundamental misunderstanding of how `async` works.  Awaiting an operation does not block, it returns control to the caller and adds a callback to the task queue to handle the result of the promise at a later time.

Comment: I don't want to make a science of it... I'm not interested in the low level stuff that's happening in the background. It just should behave the way I need it. I don't need explanations why things are like this - all this does not help. Using JavaScript was required because the project runs on a Java-based middleware that runs a Rhino or GraalVM JS engine... and so far it used JDBC drivers to connect to a database and this was "blocking" the code. Now it's moving to Node.js and this seems to be the wrong choice?!?

Comment: You should be interested in it. You are _using_ this stuff, so you ought to know how it operates! Otherwise you can't make informed decisions. Yes, having some JDBC driver that was blocking is the wrong choice in hindsight, but you can't change the past. Moving to node.js means a complete refactoring - for the better. It just happens to use the same _language_ (in fact that's a stretch too because it probably uses a much newer version of the language), but it's a completely different environment, with different rules and different ways to do things. That's how it is, accept it and move on!

Comment: @droptix: If you don't want to understand JavaScript then that's definitely going to present a challenge in writing your JavaScript code.  *"Now it's moving to Node.js and this seems to be the wrong choice?"* - If you don't want to use JavaScript then, yes, Node.js was not the right tool to use.

Comment: It's not that I don't understand the (basic) concept of Promises. I absolutely like using it in web browsers when fetching data asynchronously. But I don't like when a programming language forces me into a certain application design. And obviously I was absolutely surprised (actually shocked) that a Node.js database driver behaves different to JDBC. Simply the fact that the JDBC variant under GraalVM runs non-async shows that it IS possible but not implemented in Node.js. I wished I could choose whether to use sync or async design. Not having this choice forces a full refactoring of my app :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constructor` cannot be `async`; however, the other methods can. We'll make those `async` and we'll instantiate the object and invoke it's methods from within an `async` main function:

```
const sql = {
  connect: (config) => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({query: (sql) => sql}), 2000)
  })
}

// Existing project structure
class Foo {
  db;

  constructor() {
    this.db = null;
  }

  async db_connect() {
    this.db = await sql.connect();
  }

  async db_query(sql) {
    return await this.db.query(sql);
  }
}

const main = async () => {
  const foo = new Foo();
  await foo.db_connect()
  const out = await foo.db_query(`SELECT * FROM bar WHERE spam='eggs'`)
  console.log(out);
};

main();
```

Comment: Thanks. To refactor my code, basically I have to 1. change all relevant functions/methods to async; 2. make await calls where necessary; 3. outsource all await calls from class constructors and 4. call them manually after instanciating. I'd like to share an example how to "convert" non-async to async using class extension: https://runjs.co/s/WIQ@7nkOe